# How can i make gitbash find the javac command?

Tags: javac, git-bash

I made my gitrepository and committed it. 
Inserted one java-file and wanted to to compile it ,but it gave me this:

```
Bernard@BERNARD-PC /c/users/bernard/desktop/git2 (master)
$ javac TestGUI.java
sh.exe": javac: command not found
```

It used to work in school on their computer,but at home on my laptop I cant make it work.

EDIT : I added javac as environment variable:[image]

EDIT :
Short term solution for the duration of the runtime of gitbash enter:

```
 `export PATH=$PATH:"/C/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/"`
```

Long term solution so you can reuse this command after shutting down and rebooting gitbash:
(for win7) 
Create a file called .bashrc under Users/username.
Open with notepad and add 'export PATH=$PATH:"/C/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/"'
Finished

Comment: NOTE: Remove the backticks, or this won't work. On my system, it was:
`export PATH=$PATH:"/C/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/"`
(I tried to just remove redundant backticks in the answer above, but StackOverflow complained that it was a trivial edit <6 characters, so I added this explanation!) Also, Git Bash will complain that you have an incorrect setup, but that's OK as it will generate a `~/.bash_profile` to load your `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add javac parent folder to your PATH.

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/C/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/"
```

You can [check what `PATH` your git bash shell does see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10690098/6309) (probably the [default one](https://superuser.com/a/607534/141)).

Comment: Thanks! :) Just one remaining question .When I exit gitbash and reboot it ,the command is lost. How can I set it up to remain there permanently?

Comment: @BURNS you can register that export command in a `.bashrc` file in  `C:\Users\YourUsername`. See also http://danlimerick.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/git-for-windows-tip-setting-shell-aliases-with-msysgit/ for instance.

Comment: I added a file with the command and put it under the folder with my username.http://postimg.org/image/iei1100hr/ It didnt work

Comment: I named my bashrc file,and now i removed the name with the exception of the extension . It works now permanently. Many thx! :)

Comment: @BURNS right, I didn't see your picture right aways, but the file is named `.bashrc`, not `file.bashrc` :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @VonC in a comment in the correct answer **in order to have this this command permanently added to the path** you have to:

1. Go to `C:\Users\YourUsername`
2. Open with an editor the file `.bashrc` (if is not there just create it)
3. Write the command to add the command to your path in this file:

   > export PATH=$PATH:"/C/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/"
4. Restart GitBash and it works

Answer (score 0):

The other answers did not work for me. What DID work (Windows 10) was:

1. Go to System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables
2. New System Variable
3. 'Variable name': PATH
4. 'Variable value': C\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin (or whatever your path is)
5. Restart Git Bash