# Can not recognize java command when using git bash

Tags: java, git, bash

Now I want to use git bash to run `<a href="https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Getting-Started">gremlin</a>`. However, when I ran `gremlin.sh`, it returned java command cannot be found. I can work quite well with java using eclipse on my windows laptop. So I think the building path may be the problem. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281436/how-can-i-make-gitbash-find-the-javac-command). But it did not work.

[image: This is my git bash window]

Thanks.

I have solved this problem. [This link](https://github.com/aglover/ubuntu-equip) is very useful and Java needs to be installed. Hope can help others.

Comment: Add java to the path variable, note sometimes you will need to restart windows after you do this for the changes to take effect. If you don't restart at least restart the terminal. Note this will be a duplicate question probably.

Comment: Probably just need to restart the terminal. Once you do so, `echo $PATH` to make sure the jdk/jre bin directories are on your path as expected.

Comment: @Snickers3192, I have added java to path variable before and I can use java in eclipse.

Comment: Ah, you seem to be in a container. Your image needs to embed Java if you want to use it.

Comment: Is that a vagrant generated VM? In that case, you will need to install java inside it.

Comment: How can I embed Java in it?@AlexandreFILLATRE

Comment: @FedericoNafria, yes, it is vagrant generated VM. How can I install java inside it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to have `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` to your Windows `PATH` variable. `%JAVA_HOME%` should point to your JRE or JDK installation.

Comment: Hi Alexandre, I have set the java home to the Windows variable and I can use java in both eclipse and windows cmd