# How do you completely remove Ionic and Cordova installation from mac?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

How can I remove Cordova and ionic installation from my Mac completely? I am running mac os Yosemite 10.10.2

Answer (score 77, accepted):

BlueBell's answer is right, you can do it by:

```
npm uninstall cordova ionic
```

Are you planning to re-install it? If you feel something's wrong which is causing problems then you should update npm and clean **npm**'s cache.

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install npm -g
```

If problems still persist, I'd suggest re-install of NPM and Node.

```
npm uninstall node
apt-get purge npm
apt-get install npm
npm install node -g
```

Let me know if you face issues in the process.

Comment: apt-get is not available for OS X. How can purge npm. I can install npm using Homebrew.

Comment: Even after I run 'nom uninstall cordova ionic', it's still there. I can type ionic -v and get a version or type ionic serve and it still executes. I need to uninstall it completely.

Answer (score 74):

To uninstall Ionic and Cordova:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g cordova
sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
```

To install:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

Comment: Other answers did not have the required -g on the command line. Your version worked fine for me. Thanks!

Comment: @SaeedD That is because you have installed Cordova using -g which means globally. Otherwise -g wouldn't have needed.

Comment: it worked for me to get uninstall the setup form my machine.

Answer (score 5):

Command to remove Cordova and ionic

- For Window system

  - **npm uninstall -g ionic**
  - **npm uninstall -g cordova**
- For Mac system

  - **sudo npm uninstall -g ionic**
  - **sudo npm uninstall -g cordova**
- For install cordova and ionic

  - npm install -g cordova
  - npm install -g ionic

### Note:

- If you want to install in MAC System use before npm use *sudo* only.
- And plan to install specific version of ionic and cordova then use @(version no.).

eg.

```
sudo npm install -g cordova@6.0.0

sudo npm install -g ionic@2.1.18
```

Answer (score 5):

Try that.
Worked for me.

```
npm uninstall -g @ionic/cli
```

Answer (score 3):

Here the command to remove cordova and ionic from your machine

```
npm uninstall cordova ionic
```

Comment: This looks like a comment on the question not an attempt at an answer; please post it as such or rewrite how you are answering.

Answer (score 3):

These commands worked for me:

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm uninstall -g ionic
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to delete ionic and cordova at same time.Run this code in cmd

```
npm uninstall -g ionic cordova
```

Answer (score 1):

command to remove cordova and ionic

```
sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following command if you uninstall globally

```
npm uninstall -g cordova ionic
```

option g for global

if you want to uninstall from he drive then you can use following command

```
npm uninstall cordova ionic
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) first remove cordova cmd**

> npm uninstall -g cordova

**2) After that remove ionic**

> npm uninstall -g ionic

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had to use:

```
npm uninstall @ionic/cli
```

to stop ionic from still being active.

Comment: That worked for me (with -g switch) to remove globally on MacOS big sur. npm uninstall -g @ionic/cli

Answer (score 1):

for mac users, please try

```
sudo npm uninstall -g @ionic/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

If still facing issue after running all command then you can just delete it from local npm directory.

`C:\App>where ionic`

It will return below file names. Navigate to folder and delete them manually.

1. C:\Program Files\nodejs\ionic
2. C:\Program Files\nodejs\ionic.cmd