# Ionic Framework - App doesn't display to Browser after 'ionic serve'

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I installd ionic using: npm install

```
-g cordova ionic
```

and created a tabs project using:

```
ionic start myApp tabs
```

Then I used:

```
ionic serve
```

to see the app on the browser which is Google Chrome. It opened to a url localhost:8100 but it cannot load the page.

UPDATE:

Well, I discovered something i tried changing the address to my wifi address using 'ionic address'. I accessed the app using my PC's browsers(everything). The when I accessed it using my phone's browser. It worked. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Can upload an image to see your error clearly?

Comment: @trungk18 there's no error. The localhost:8100 just doesn't load any page.

Comment: Can you open localhost:8100 on Chrome with Developer Tool to see If there are any missing file ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Chrome console says: GET http://localhost:8100/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: It is probably because of you have already close the console while you are trying to open the localhost:8100. 
After run ionic serve, did you close the cmd ? You have to keep it to active live reloading.

Comment: @trungk18 No, i didn't close cmd. It automatically loads the url but still says connection time out.

Comment: Still not easy to conclude. Have you tried create another project with another template ?

Comment: @trungk18 yes, i tried sidemenu, blank and tabs. But still not loading.

Comment: What I can suggest you now for save time is remove ionic completely and install it again.

Comment: i used the code npm uninstall cordova ionic but it didn't uninstall it.

Comment: try this one for uninstalling and re-install again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428929/how-do-you-completely-remove-ionic-and-cordova-installation-from-mac

Comment: for remove ionic follow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428929/how-do-you-completely-remove-ionic-and-cordova-installation-from-mac if you are using mac machine please tyoe "sudo" before all commands.

Comment: i uninstalled all. Deleted the modules and downloaded a new version of node js but still when I got all back, still not working.

Comment: @trungk18 Well, I discovere something i tried changing the address to my wifi address using 'ionic address'. I accessed the app using my PC's browsers(everything). The when I accessed it using my phone's browser. It worked. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by 'ionic address'? Seem you changed the ip address of your wifi to it, but what is this ? :D

Comment: @trungk18 instead of using my localhost ip, i used my wifi's ip. And tried to access the project using my phone and it worked. But my pc still cannot load the project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow tasks:

> 1) npm install -g cordova ionic .
>
> 2) ionic start myApp tabs
>
> 3) cd myApp
>
> 4) ionic serve

you missed 3rd point `cd myApp`

Please fire all above command if still issue persist try to debugg error in browser console and update your question.

Thank you.

Comment: I didn't miss that sorry. When I run ionic serve, the browser directs me to localhost:8100, but it don't load any page.

Comment: The console says: GET http://localhost:8100/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: have you add whitelist plugin?

Comment: if not please follow https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/

Comment: it's for security enable disable one.. please go through above link for more info...

Comment: Why do I have to put that? My friend was able to view his app without any edits.

Comment: Well, I discovere something i tried changing the address to my wifi address using 'ionic address'. I accessed the app using my PC's browsers(everything). The when I accessed it using my phone's browser. It worked. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: That may be your machine's firewall issue.. i go throguh some links for trying to solve your issue i found one isssue happend with firewall of system..can't exactly tell you but it may be cause.. i glad that you resolve your problem.. happy coding.. cheers...

Comment: Well I still haven't solved it. Well I will try to close my firewall. Thanks