# Ionic 2 - Can't generate pages via the CLI how to resolve error?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

This may be just my lack of experience working with ionic 2 but I'm getting an error when tying to generate pages via the CLI.

The syntax I'm using: "ionic g page TestPage"

It returns an error (below).  Does anyone know how to resolve this error?  It seems the "templates" directory does not exist on my machine which I gather is why this is happening, but not sure how to get it there or fix the issue.  The first part of the path does exist:  C:\apps\sampleapp\node_modules\ionic-angular\, but not the "templates/page" part.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\apps\sampleapp\node_modules\ionic-angular\templates\page'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:808:18)
at getTemplatesInDir (C:\Users\m411\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\app-generator
at Generator.renderAndWriteTemplates (C:\Users\m411\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ion
at C:\Users\m411\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\app-generators\index.js:25304:26
```

Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11

Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0-beta.1

Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.0

OS: Windows 8.1

Node Version: v4.5.0

Comment: Do you have ionic-angular/templates directory in your node modules? Did you npm install properly?

Comment: No @misha130 - The templates directory is missing.  I'm not sure why or what causes it to be there unfortunately.  I did run "npm install" in my project directory, but the folder you mentioned is not there

Comment: Actually I checked and for me its located in tooling/generators instead of templates/. Maybe switch down to Ionic CLI version 2.0.0 beta 32?

Comment: Faced the same issue with Ionic '2.1.0-beta.1'. I swichted to Ionic version 2.0.0. Its working now. Please try that.

Comment: Thanks for the help here guys, how can I downgrade my version @Madhukar?

Comment: To downgrade your `ionic` *version* just run the following: `npm i -g ionic@2.0.0-beta.37`.

Comment: I would suggest going for `npm i -g ionic@2.0.0`. Hope this would help.

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade your ionic version to beta 22.. I think it works by uninstalling and then updating npm just in case and then reinstalling a lower ionic version.

[How do you completely remove Ionic and Cordova installation from mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428929/how-do-you-completely-remove-ionic-and-cordova-installation-from-mac)

And I would suggest trying "npm install" in the project directory after this too.

Answer (score 0):

`npm i -g ionic@2.0.0` - Solved the issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for anyone where downgrading is not an option:

The Ionic Team did some major API updates and some restructuring.
You need to follow these upgrade steps:

Sidenote: If you did uninstall and reinstall the package AND did run the command with `sudo` and hit the command `ionic start --v2 myApp` in the same terminal, then you need to update the rights in your folder with:
`sudo chown -R username ./pathToAppFolder`

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#steps-to-upgrade-to-rc0

Answer (score 0):

`npm i -g ionic@2.0.0-beta.37` 
resolved the issue for me, was previously on **ionic 2.0.0 beta 11**