# Upgrade Ionic to latest version

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to upgrade Ionic to the latest version. Looking [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic), it shows that the latest version is `3.0.0`. I also follow [this](http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-cli-v3/) tutorial.

So I do the following:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
sudo npm install -g ionic@latest
```

console:

```
Richards-MacBook-Pro:theWhoZoo richardmarais$ sudo npm install -g ionic
Password:
/Users/richardmarais/npm-global/bin/ionic -> /Users/richardmarais/npm-global/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic
/Users/richardmarais/npm-global/lib
└── ionic@3.0.0
```

But when I run:

```
ionic -v
```

I get:

```
2.1.18
```

and:

```
ionic info
```

I get:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.1.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.10.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
```

I would expect it to update the `Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18` to `3.0.0`. Is that a correct assumption?  If so, do you know what I am doing incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: `ionic -v` is CLI of ionic framework, so the version is correct and version of ionic framework itself is correct.
UPD: I didn't say that's a last version of CLI because it's [not](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: @DjezzzL:  That should be an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: What is the latest version of the `CLI`, `2.1.18`? So am I on the latest version? What about this, announcing cli v3? http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-cli-v3/

Comment: @Richard  You used `sudo` for install ionic. Could you share your output of `sudo ionic -v`?

Comment: `sudo ionic -v` 

'2.1.18' and

`ionic -v`

'2.1.18'

Comment: Right now I tried to update my ionic via this commands:
`npm uninstal -g ionic` then I got correct error with `ionic -v` and then I install latest via `npm install -g ionic@latest`. So now I have following outputs:
`ionic -v => 3.0.0` and `ionic info => global packages: @ionic/cli-utils : 1.0.0 Ionic CLI        : 3.0.0 and so on`

Comment: @Richard so try to [full remove](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29429357/5775246) ionic then check that nor `ionic -v` or `sudo ionic -v` work and then install that like I did in comment before.

Comment: When I run `npm uninstall cordova ionic`, and then `ionic info`, I still get `Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18`. or `ionic -v` I still get `2.1.18`. So I guess the uninstall is not correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144267/discussion-between-djezzzl-and-richard).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We did big chat. Things which were helpful:

1. Be sure that you completely delete all previous version with `npm uninstall -g ionic` or manually from `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules`. Don't forget remove symlink too: `rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ionic`
2. After completely deletion you should see error: command not found of `ionic -v`
3. And now if your `npm root -g` path is right like `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` try to install `npm install -g ionic@latest`. Then you should get correct output of `ionic -v`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If like me, the removal of the symlink caused the command ionic -v to stop working even after reinstalling ionic, create the symlink manually by issuing the following command "ln -s <path given by npm root -g>/ionic/bin/ionic /usr/local/bin/ionic".

Answer (score 10):

The ionic CLI package has been renamed @ionic/cli
https://twitter.com/ionicframework/status/1223268498362851330

So you should uninstall ionic from your global

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
```

and add the new package name.

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli@latest
```

*In case anyone comes here from google.*

Answer (score 7):

I simple run

```
$ ionic --version
$ 4.2.1
$ sudo npm i -g ionic@latest 
$ ionic --version
$ 4.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start trying the simple things before.

I just ran...

```
npm --version
```

Then, the answer was...

```
4.6.0
   ╭──────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                      │
   │   Update available 4.6.0 → 4.12.0    │
   │     Run npm i -g ionic to update     │
   │                                      │
   ╰──────────────────────────────────────╯
```

So, I did...

```
npm i -g ionic to update
```

After that...

```
npm --version
6.5.0
```