# Uninstalling Cordova and Ionic not working

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to uninstall Cordova and Ionic from my mac. I have run `sudo npm uninstall ionic cordova` and also with `-g` however when I run `cordova --version` or `ionic --versions` it keeps coming back with version numbers and it all still works normally.

I have checked the directories of both local and global npm install locations and the folders aren't there, when I run the command after the first time it throws an error that it can't find the folders.

I have gone so far as to completely remove NodeJS from my machine but to no avail. Where else is cordova and ionic installed? How do I completely remove them from my machine?

Comment: check this thread see if it helps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428929/how-do-you-completely-remove-ionic-and-cordova-installation-from-mac

Comment: This thread did not work, did everything other than the apt-get commands as I am on OSX, cordova and ionic still somewhere on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

So for some reason, npm uninstall does not deal with the files in the `opt` directory, found the rougue folders and removed. Problem solved.