# ionic is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Tags: ionic-framework

I have tried to install ionic framework. I was done with my first step by executing the command (installed node.js).

First command: npm install -g cordova ionic

But the second command is not executing instead stating"ionic is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file  "

Second command:ionic start myApp tabs

I request to help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to install ionic in windows.
I think you could try to install it alone, without cordova, and then try it again.

```
npm install -g ionic
```

Regards

Comment: Hello Pablo Thanks... It doesn't work too and I am working on windows

Comment: probably you may add the path of the ionic installation directory to the PATH environment of windows in order to be available to use it. I never have used ionic on windows, sorry if this is not useful.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using windows 10 for developing, I solved it by adding the npm global packages folder:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

to the environment variable **Path**

Comment: This worked for me because i moved my appdata from the C:\ drive to another drive. I added %APPDATA%\npm to the Path variable, and that fixed it

Answer (score 1):

İf "ionic" is installed;

1-Download and upgrade nodejs to latest version.
[download nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

2- run command:

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
```

3-Clear these files:

C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm

C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

3-run command:

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli
```

İt is done:)

Answer (score 0):

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%
```

Is worked for me on Windows 10 :)