# Why can't Git Bash run my executable?

Tags: windows, git, bash, mingw-w64, msys2

I am on [git-for-windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/) Git Bash. I can't run an executable on the command line:

```
Pedr@Abc-07 MINGW64 /c/dev
$ ls sqlite3.exe
sqlite3.exe*

Pedr@Abc-07 MINGW64 /c/dev
$ sqlite3
bash: sqlite3: command not found
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

To run a program in the current directory in bash, you put `./` in front of it. So in your case:

```
$ ./sqlite3.exe
```

When you run `sqlite3`, bash will look for a program with exactly that name in all directories of the `PATH` environment variable, which by default includes standard locations for executables like `/usr/local/bin` but not your current directory. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10681101/3511560) for more info on that.

Comment: Thanks. I was used to being able to do so from msysgit Git bash.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't figure this one out myself. Something I am pretty dumb. Thank you.

Comment: Also works for the bash in the Windows Subsystem for Linux

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're under a is a runtime environment for gcc, that give you support to binaries native under Windows, but you can run any exe as shell using ./ (local execute)
Take a look to documentation of this tool: http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/FAQ/

Answer (score 1):

Your PATH is missing `./`. Add it to your `.profile` file in the home directory (`/c/Users/username`):

```
$ cd
$ pwd
/c/Users/username
$ echo 'PATH=$PATH:./' >> .profile
```

Restart bash session and voilà! Now `echo $PATH` should output `:./` as the last item. Note that you definitely need to add it as the **last** item for security (e.g. against malicious `ls.exe`).