# Ionic and Cordova is installed but commands not recognized

Tags: node.js, git, bash, cordova, ionic-framework

I install ionic and cordova globally but the commands aren't recognized.

I'm on Win 7 - 64bit
Latest Nodejs is installed

This is the install log :

```
$ npm install -g cordova
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"4.1.1","npm":"2.14.4"})
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\cordova -> C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
cordova@5.3.3 C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules\cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.7)
└── cordova-lib@5.3.3 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, unorm@1.3.3, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, semver@4.3.6, shelljs@0.3.0, cordova-app-hello-world@3.9.0, dep-graph@1.1.0, rc@0.5.2, elementtree@0.1.6, xcode@0.8.0, glob@5.0.15, npmconf@2.1.2, tar@1.0.2, cordova-serve@0.1.3, request@2.47.0, aliasify@1.7.2, cordova-registry-mapper@1.1.12, init-package-json@1.9.1, plist@1.1.0, cordova-js@4.1.1, npm@2.14.7)


$ npm install -g ionic
npm WARN engine cordova-js@4.0.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"4.1.1","npm":"2.14.4"})
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"4.1.1","npm":"2.14.4"})
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"4.1.1","npm":"2.14.4"})
npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\ionic -> C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic
ionic@1.6.5 C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules\ionic
├── connect-livereload@0.5.2
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── proxy-middleware@0.7.0
├── progress@1.1.7
├── open@0.0.5
├── colors@0.6.2
├── q@1.0.1
├── async@0.9.2
├── crc@3.2.1
├── ncp@0.4.2
├── semver@4.3.6
├── shelljs@0.2.6
├── cross-spawn@0.2.3 (lru-cache@2.7.0)
├── optimist@0.6.0 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
├── cli-table@0.3.1 (colors@1.0.3)
├── finalhandler@0.2.0 (escape-html@1.0.1, debug@2.0.0)
├── connect@3.1.1 (utils-merge@1.0.0, parseurl@1.3.0, finalhandler@0.1.0, debug@1.0.4)
├── form-data@0.1.4 (mime@1.2.11, combined-stream@0.0.7)
├── event-stream@3.0.20 (pause-stream@0.0.11, stream-combiner@0.0.4, from@0.1.3, duplexer@0.1.1, split@0.2.10, through@2.3.8, map-stream@0.0.6)
├── opbeat-ionic@1.1.3 (console-log-level@1.1.2, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, stackman@0.2.3, after-all@2.0.2)
├── serve-static@1.7.1 (utils-merge@1.0.0, escape-html@1.0.1, parseurl@1.3.0, send@0.10.1)
├── tiny-lr-fork@0.0.5 (debug@0.7.4, qs@0.5.6, faye-websocket@0.4.4, noptify@0.0.3)
├── request@2.51.0 (forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0, caseless@0.8.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.1, oauth-sign@0.5.0, stringstream@0.0.4, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, mime-types@1.0.2, qs@2.3.3, node-uuid@1.4.3, tough-cookie@2.0.0, combined-stream@0.0.7, http-signature@0.10.1, form-data@0.2.0, bl@0.9.4, hawk@1.1.1)
├── vinyl-fs@0.3.7 (graceful-fs@3.0.8, lodash@2.4.2, strip-bom@1.0.0, vinyl@0.4.6, mkdirp@0.5.1, through2@0.6.5, glob-stream@3.1.18, glob-watcher@0.0.6)
├── unzip@0.1.9 (setimmediate@1.0.2, readable-stream@1.0.33, pullstream@0.4.1, match-stream@0.0.2, binary@0.3.0, fstream@0.1.31)
├── prompt@0.2.12 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.7, utile@0.2.1, winston@0.6.2)
├── gulp@3.8.8 (interpret@0.3.10, pretty-hrtime@0.2.2, deprecated@0.0.1, archy@0.0.2, minimist@1.2.0, semver@3.0.1, tildify@1.1.1, chalk@0.5.1, orchestrator@0.3.7, gulp-util@3.0.6, liftoff@0.12.1)
├── cheerio@0.19.0 (entities@1.1.1, dom-serializer@0.1.0, css-select@1.0.0, htmlparser2@3.8.3, lodash@3.10.1)
├── xml2js@0.4.4 (sax@0.6.1, xmlbuilder@3.1.0)
├── npm@2.1.3
└── ionic-app-lib@0.3.9 (vinyl-fs@1.0.0, archiver@0.5.2, ionic-cordova-lib@5.1.7)


$ cordova
bash: cordova: command not found


$ ionic
bash: ionic: command not found
```

Here's the list of variables inside my system environment Path :

```
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm;
C:\Android;C:\Android\sdk;
C:\Android\sdk\platforms;
C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools;
C:\Android\sdk\tools;
C:\Android\sdk\platforms\android-19;
C:\Android\sdk\platforms;
C:\Android\sdk\platforms-tools;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;
C:\Android\sdk\tools;
C:\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin;
C:\Program Files\nodejs;
C:\Android\sdk\system-images;
```

Fixes I have done so far without luck :

1. Reinstall nodejs
2. npm cache clean
3. Manually cleared npm-cache folder and installed ionic + cordova

Is there something that I'm missing? Why can't I use ionic?

Please do tell if additional info is required :)

P.S. I've tried many threads on the same issue here and also in ionic forums but non of the fixes worked, that's why I decided to put up my own thread!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to run it on Node 0.10? Try and say what you got.

Comment: install this stable version : https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v0.10.36/ and reinstalled ionic and cordova, still gets the command not found error :(

Comment: Uninstall all from your system and clear the npm folder from app data folder. And then install latest git and node js and try cli install command for cordova and ionic

Comment: @cfprahbu : I uninstalled git and node, then I removed all folders (Git,npm,npm cache, .ionic, .cordova) and installed the latest versions of git and nodejs, restarted my pc...typed in  " npm install -g ionic cordova " on bash. Now everything works fine! Thanks alot! :D :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, use Git Bash shell and have issues calling cordova and ionic, 
maybe you'll have to add a path value to 
c:\users[your username]**.bash_profile**
this helped comparing windows path with git bash shell path: 
[Git Bash doesn't see my PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681101/git-bash-doesnt-see-my-path)
for me, global paths were there, but user paths not. I had to add: 
**PATH=$PATH:**/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft VS Code/bin:**/C/Users/[my username]/AppData/Roaming/npm**