# adb: command not found in Git Bash

Tags: android, command, adb, git-bash

I am using Git Bash on Windows 8. Whenever I type
`$ adb devices`
I get
`bash: adb: command not found`
I have already added the path to the PATH variable.

Answer (score 5):

if you haven't solved the problem yet, try adding an alias to your adb.exe 
place yourself in the git $home folder

*cd $home*

if you haven't created the .bashrc file yet
Execute

*touch .bahsrc*

thereupon

*vi .bashrc*

add the following line to the file

*alias adb='/c/adb/platform-tools/adb.exe'*

*note: this path is relative, it depends on where you unzipped the .zip from adb
and save the changes made in vi with *ESC* then *:wq!*

Comment: For a standard AndroidStudio install on Windows: `alias adb='C:\\Users\\[username]\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe'`

Comment: typo in touch .bahsrc

Answer (score 1):

GitBash is a Terminal-Emulation software using CYGWIN. The ADB command is a Windows binary that is availabe in a Windows Command Prompt via PATH-variable.

Check this question: [Git Bash doesn't see my PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681101/git-bash-doesnt-see-my-path)

Answer (score 1):

It's works my windows machine.
Run the following command on your windows bash profile terminal

```
echo export "PATH=~/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Restart your Terminal session

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to My Computer-> Right click -> properties

C:\Users\PCNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools