# Python 3 won't run from the Git Bash command line

Tags: python, git, bash, shell

Basically, I type `python` into Git Bash command line and I get back a blank line as if the command line is thinking...

I've done plenty of research but I can't seem to run python on Git Bash by typing in python into the command line.

I was looking at the question: [Python not working in the command line of git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597209/python-not-working-in-the-command-line-of-git-bash)
and someone recommended to type:

```sh
winpty c:/Python34/python.exe
```

into the command line and it worked! However, I don't want to have to keep typing that entire command into the command line.

Comment: I would assume adding it to [~/.bashrc](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6883798/1068887) would make it work each time.

Comment: A few of the solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10764080/3079347) should help you out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python not working in the command line of git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597209/python-not-working-in-the-command-line-of-git-bash) (I see that you found that question already; but note that (at the moment of writing) there are some solutions there that use `alias` and that is permanent)

Answer (score 6):

> "One caveat if using Git Bash with MinTTY: python doesn't go into
>   interactive mode so a solution is to force it to start that way: echo
>   alias python=\"python -i\" >> ~/.bash_profile"]

[For more details](https://www.trueneutral.eu/2017/python-git-win.html)

I had the same issue and using "python -i" solved it.

Answer (score 4):

The comment of adding it to the .bashrc is likely the best answer.

Type:

1. open terminal
2. cd ~  (hit enter)
3. vim .bashrc   (hit enter)
4. Hit I to insert
   on one of the lines and type:
5. alias python3='c:/Python34/python.exe'
6. hit esc  (enters vim command mode)
7. type :wq  (write and quit)
8. hit enter

Now type python3 in gitbash hit enter and there you go!

Comment: you might want to add a 9th step: source `~/.bashrc` or quit and reopen terminal, else you might not see the alias in your terminal.

Answer (score 3):

A few of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764080/3079347) should help you out.

Or, as @adarsh suggests, add the following to ~/.bashrc (or in ~/.bash_profile if this doesn't work for your version of Git Bash):

```
PATH=$PATH:c/Python34/
```

Comment: bonus: if you add it to your Windows path (system or user) rather than in your .bashrc, then it will be usable from both `cmd.exe` and git bash, as git bash will respect your environment path.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two version of Python installed I would just point exe independently. 
example:

*$ '/d/Python 3.6.4/python.exe' /d/1.APPS/gitHUBprojects/project1/project1.py*

Answer (score 2):

@Mindputty's answer above worked best for me -- in `.bash_profile` -- with the addition of the `-i` option:

```
alias py="winpty C:/Python38/python.exe -i"
```

Also added:

```
alias py="winpty C:/Python38/python.exe -i"
```

I'm on Windows 10 (64-bit) with git-for-windows 2.25.windows.1 and python 3.8.2.

(@Mindputty - sorry, don't have enough cred to upvote. But thank you--this was driving me crazy.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you were asking specifically about needing to type it again and again, you'll probably want to create an alias in your .bashrc or .bash_profile file:

`alias python="winpty C:/Python34/python.exe"`