# Can I use gcloud in Git Bash on Windows?

Tags: git-bash, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

So, I've installed Git, Git Bash, Python2.7, and I've just installed the Google Cloud SDK [per the official guide.](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/)  Using Windows 10.

In cmd.exe, or the "Google Cloud SDK Shell",  `gcloud` works fine.

Within Git Bash, however (the terminal that I prefer to use), `gcloud` returns the following output (screenshot).

[image]

`echo $PATH` in Git Bash does include the path to the Google SDK (highlighted here).

[image]

Am I missing something?  Is there anything in $PATH that is possibly conflicting with gcloud, or did I misconfigure the path somehow?

I appreciate any insight.

---

UPDATE. Here is the output of `env|grep PATH`.  I'm not sure what it tells me. Any other executable in the PATH is working (vagrant, conda, python, etc), but gcloud is not.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Bash doesn't see my PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681101/git-bash-doesnt-see-my-path)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use the full file name i.e. gcloud.sh or gcloud.cmd. See the following question for more details:

[Git Bash doesn't see my PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681101/git-bash-doesnt-see-my-path)

Comment: This works!  `gcloud.cmd` works for me.  Is there any way to account for this?

Comment: Thanks for confirming it works. Can you clarify what you mean by 'account for this'?

Comment: Sorry.  Is there any way to 'correct' this, so that I do not have to append the file extension, and can use the command normally?

Comment: Git Bash is working as it should since bash does not let you omit file extensions. You could create an executable shortcut called gcloud to gcloud.cmd in the same bin directory.

Answer (score 33):

Create `~/.bashrc` with one and only line:

```
alias gcloud="gcloud.cmd"
```

and restart you shell session. That's it.

Answer (score 15):

Put the following in a .bashrc file which should be located in C:\Users\YourWindowsAccount:

```
gcloud() {
    "gcloud.cmd" "$@"
}
export -f gcloud
```

Adapted from: https://askubuntu.com/a/98791

Restart Git Bash thereafter.

This solution is better than using aliases because it allows you to call gcloud from a shell script also.

Answer (score 0):

Another option - copying the `gsutil` and `bq` files from Linux version to /google-cloud-sdk/bin on Windows.