# how to run .bat or .cmd files from Bash for Windows 10

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, gcloud

`gcloud.cmd` is a Windows command-line script. I am trying to run it from the Bash shell installed on Windows 10. It is recognized by the CMD prompt, but not by “Bash for Windows 10”.

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843983/can-i-use-gcloud-in-git-bash-on-windows) I created a `.bashrc` file with this entry:

`PATH=$PATH:/mnt/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin`

It seems that Bash now finds the file because when I run `gcloud.cmd` it shows:

```
/mnt/c/Users/***/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud.cmd: line 1: @echo: command not found
/mnt/c/Users/***/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud.cmd: line 2: rem: command not found
/mnt/c/Users/***/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud.cmd: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/mnt/c/Users/***/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud.cmd: line 7: `rem <cloud-sdk-cmd-preamble>'
```

I also tried the following commands because Cygwin seems to recognize `.bat` files automatically:

```bash
cmd.exe gcloud.cmd
cmd gcloud.cmd 
cmd gcloud
cmd /c gcloud
cmd /c glcoud.cmd
```

All of the above commands show:

```
No command 'cmd' found, did you mean: (…)
```

How do I run Windows Batch commands from Bash?

Comment: I haven't used bash on windows so don't know this will work, but have you tried `cmd /c gcloud` or similar, so the `gcloud` command would be executed in a `cmd` shell instead of directly in the `bash` shell?

Comment: Yeah.. I was just thinking about this. It seems CYGWIN runs .bat files automatically in the native interpreter (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787522/why-is-it-that-cygwin-can-run-bat-scripts). I have tried the following

cmd.exe gcloud.cmd;
cmd gcloud.cmd;
cmd gcloud;
cmd /c gcloud;
cmd /c glcoud.cmd

Comment: none of the above work.. perhaps I should move to cygwin, or install linux in a virtual machine..

Comment: It's hard for people to find information in the comments, and they don't format well,  Instead, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44739204/edit) your question to include the updated attempts, and it would probably be helpful to include exact error messages when available instead of a variation on "it didn't work."

Comment: ok.. no problem!

Comment: Have you tried to use a full path to cmd.exe?  as in `/mnt/c/windows/system32/cmd.exe /C gcloud.cmd`   You may also want to include /mnt/c/windows/system32/ to your PATH

Comment: Thanks.. i just did. Didnt work unfortunately. The only way I found it to work is by getting out of the bash shell using the following in sequence 1. cmd.exe 2. gcloud.cmd 3. exit. however, I was trying to run gcloud.cmd along with some parameters, and pass the output to grep. Grep is installed in the bash shell, and not in the windows command. So I couldnt get it working..

Comment: also the PATH maynot be issue here.. because cmd.exe is recognized regardless of which directory I am in, in the bash shell.

Comment: Did you read [Bash on Ubuntu on Windows - Bash-Windows Interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/interop)?

Comment: Thanks LotPings. I think I maybe able to work with this..

Comment: The `PATH=…` line looks wrong because it contains a space: it should be double-quoted or escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to post this as an answer but I cannot yet comment. I was thinking that maybe you could have a batch file that calls bash scripts, then once they exit, it starts to bat files, then starts more bash scripts? You could split your code in too... Just an idea.

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify the full path to cmd.exe.

I have added the following to my ~/.bash_aliases:

```
alias cmd='/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c'
```

with this you can run *.bat files with:

```
$ cmd ./test.bat
```

Comment: The alias method works, however you will have to adjust the path, because `cmd` will not be able to comprehend `./test.bat`. So you will either have to simply pass `test.bat` without `./` if you are in the directory where your batch file is located, or you need to pass the full path, *i.e.* use a command like this: `cmd 'C:\MyFolder\MySubfolder\test.bat'`.