# django OSError: no library called "cairo" was found on windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, cairo, pycairo

When I run the Django server, I see this problem !!

```
OSError: no library called "cairo" was found

no library called "libcairo-2" was found

cannot load library 'libcairo.so': error 0x7e

cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x

cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e
```

Comment: Please can you provide more details eg Version of Djano, version of Windows.

Comment: The output of `pip freeze` would be useful here. How are you running your Django project? with manage.py?

Comment: Can we get the operation system as well as its version?

Comment: Are you using weasyprint in your project?

Comment: I am facing the same issue ,i am using django-weasyprint.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WeasyPrint needs the Pango, cairo and GDK-PixBuf libraries. They are part of GTK+ (formerly known as GIMP Toolkit), and must be installed separately.

After installing [GTK+ libraries](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#windows), do :

```
python -m weasyprint http://weasyprint.org weasyprint.pdf
```

Comment: I am still getting this error even after installing the GTK

Comment: Do not forget to add the installed GTK+ lib to your system path, and restart your IDE so that the changes take effect.

Comment: @Mathador agree.

Comment: @Mathador how do i add them to the path?

Comment: Follow the instructions here: "http://gisaxs.com/index.php/View.gtk_installation" and replace "C:\GTK\bin" with the actual path where you installed the GTK package on your drive.

Answer (score 12):

Installing GTK+ didn't work for me.
I solved this problem using [UniConverter2.0](https://sk1project.net/uc2/).
My environments is

- Python 3.7
- Windows 10 x64

1. Install [uniconvertor-2.0rc4-win64_headless.msi](https://downloads.sk1project.net/uniconvertor/2.0rc4/uniconvertor-2.0rc4-win64_headless.msi),
2. Find the "dll" sub-directory under the UniConverter installation path.(In my case, `C:\Program Files\UniConvertor-2.0rc4\dlls`)
3. Add this "dll" path to the system path.
4. Close VSCode and reopen the project.
5. Try to run the server again.
   Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

Starting from Python 3.8, dll's need to be added separately.
Added GTK+, MSYS2, Visual Studio C Compiler and Uniconverter. But, nothing seemed to work.
Finally, got it working after putting the script for calling add_dll_directory.

```
import os

def set_dll_search_path():
   # Python 3.8 no longer searches for DLLs in PATH, so we have to add
   # everything in PATH manually. Note that unlike PATH add_dll_directory
   # has no defined order, so if there are two cairo DLLs in PATH we
   # might get a random one.
   if os.name != "nt" or not hasattr(os, "add_dll_directory"):
       return
   for p in os.environ.get("PATH", "").split(os.pathsep):
       try:
           os.add_dll_directory(p)
       except OSError:
           pass


set_dll_search_path()
```

Source: [PyCairo Windows Python3.8 Import Issue](https://github.com/pygobject/pycairo/blob/8c5d0c700cb4b49bff1092dca498ef3e75439a26/tests/__init__.py#L6)

Comment: OMG this is what fixed for me after nothing else.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See the solution here:

https://www.programmersought.com/article/47674569357/

You will need to add a path if not added after installations:

**C:\Program Files\GTK3-Runtime Win64\bin**

I have been solving it many times this way.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a lightweight Linux Docker Image, it may not include GTK as said above, then, you can include it by adding in your Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install python3-cffi python3-brotli libpango-1.0-0 libharfbuzz0b libpangoft2-1.0-0 libgtk-3-dev gcc -y
```

Where all those packages are recommended to be installed by weasyprint and GCC has the GTK.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: https://cairocffi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#installing-cairo-on-windows

And maybe this will work to: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycairo](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pycairo)

Best option is instal cairocffi trough pipwin

```
pip install pipwin

pipwin install cairocffi
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figure this out. you can have a 64 bit version of python that doesn't work. What I have found to work and this could change is the installing the 64 bit version of python from python's website, not from the Microsoft store!

1. remove any version of python you have installed
2. download https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.10/python-3.8.10-amd64.exe
3. install
4. download and install https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer/releases

   1. exact link is https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer/releases/download/2021-04-29/gtk3-runtime-3.24.29-2021-04-29-ts-win64.exe
   2. note that link is from https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/stable/first_steps.html#windows
5. add bin folder from that (sorry it was somebody else's machine, I use Ubuntu) in your environment path.
6. run through the first steps on weasyprint and you should be good to go!

Comment: Yep, that did the trick! Seems to be an issue with Python installed from the Microsoft Store. I took Python 3.10.1 and it worked for me. Maybe just don’t put a direct link to a specific Python installer, just point to the official website like you did for the GTK installer. Also note that this way of installing Python does not provide the `python3` command-line alias. [Just use `python` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40931434/525036).

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but I just encoutered the same issue and:
Start here: `https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#windows`. Where you will find the links for the GTK Pack that contains the required DLLs.

In my case, I have a 64bit Python, so i use: "`Download and run the latest gtk3-runtime-x.x.x-x-x-x-ts-win64.exe`"

I did not change the installation directory

Once the installation is completed. I added the path to my variable paths.

I restarted the terminal, made sure I could locate the DLLs with : `WHERE libcairo-2.dll`. This retured `C:\Program Files\GTK3-Runtime Win64\bin\libcairo-2.dll`

Then I run `python -m weasyprint http://weasyprint.org weasyprint.pdf`
and got a few WARNINGs but they are just warnings :)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same error as well

I haved installed gtk as followed as [gtk install in windows](https://www.programmersought.com/article/47674569357/)

Nothing worked

After that :

> python -m pip install pycairo

solved the problem for me