# Node.js spawn module does not work with python

Tags: python, node.js, stdout, spawn

Currently I have a very basic js and python script.
The problem is that the python text is not displayed after running the JS file in the CMD.
I am working in Windows 10 OS.

Does someone see what I am doing wrong?

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('python3', ['hello.py']);


child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```

-->

Python Code for testing:

```
import sys

data = "hallo hallo test"
print(data)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Maybe you should print stderr as well?

Comment: No, does not help unfortunately.

Comment: What if you give the full path to the hello.py?

Comment: I solved the issue! I someone encounters a similar problem: python3 was not found. The following post helped me solving it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914108/bash-python3-command-not-found-windows-discord-py