# problem installing library cr_sparse cr-sparse 0.3.2 depends on jaxlib>=0.3.14

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, jax

am trying to install cr-sparce on pycharme in windows 10 machine since yesterday
am having the following conflict :

```
python -m pip install cr-sparse
The conflict is caused by:
    cr-sparse 0.3.2 depends on jaxlib>=0.3.14
    cr-sparse 0.3.1 depends on jaxlib>=0.3.14
    cr-sparse 0.3.0 depends on jaxlib>=0.3.14
    cr-sparse 0.2.2 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
    cr-sparse 0.2.1 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
    cr-sparse 0.2.0 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
    cr-sparse 0.1.6 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
    cr-sparse 0.1.5 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
    cr-sparse 0.1.4 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
    cr-sparse 0.1.3 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

i looked it up with no success
any guidlines ?
thank you

i uninstalled jax and tried reinstalling always getting the same problem
update :
[image]

Comment: What version of jaxlib do you have installed?

Comment: i think i have not installed any,
python -m pip install jaxlib
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jaxlib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jaxlib
should i install it outside python, sorry am very new to this

Comment: It seems jaxlib requires at least Python 3.8, can you check your Python version using `python --version`?

Comment: i have version Python 3.11.2 installed

Comment: Just to be sure, can you try `python3 -m pip install jaxlib`?

Comment: it didn't work, python3 not found
but when i tape just python i get :
Python 3.11.2 (tags/v3 ...

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48279175/17200348) to access your Python 3.11.2 installation.

Comment: well i tried the same problem, i also added a photo to the post, thank you for your time

Comment: I think I found the issue. Since you're on Windows, you'll need to [build jaxlib yourself](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer.html#additional-notes-for-building-jaxlib-from-source-on-windows).