# Redirecting input/output in git bash for Windows

Tags: windows, git-bash

I am trying to run the following command in git bash for windows.

$ python Prog.py < my_input.in > my_output.out

I receive the following error: "input is not a tty"

Note: the command works fine using bash.exe of MinGW.

Any way to have the above command run on git bash for wins

Edit: bash.exe not git.exe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
python.exe Prog.py < my_input.in > my_output.out
```

Notice python.**exe**

It has to do with how `bash` needs exact matching to find a program in your environment; see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681101/git-bash-doesnt-see-my-path).

Comment: This answer would be that bit more awesome if it explained _why_ this works. It is a bit mysterious to me...