# Git Bash does not execute command included in path

Tags: git, git-bash

I have a custom application who's path is included in the PATH variable. It executes all okay when I use the windows command prompt

I open cmd and I type myapp and I can see the results. However, when I use git bash to run the same command, I get an error - bad interpreter: No such file or directory.

Do I have do anything different to add the application to the PATH variable for git bash? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Bash doesn't see my PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681101/git-bash-doesnt-see-my-path)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think git-bash will fetch the windows environment/path variables. You can run export command to include your app to current path

> export PATH=$PATH:path_to_your_app

If you want to have this permanently, add the line above to your ~/.bashrc. If .bashrc file is not found, create one.