# Git bash updating PATH

Tags: git-bash

Can't update my path in git bash, I followed the guide by Mikaël Mayer in this post
[Git Bash doesn't see my PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681101/git-bash-doesnt-see-my-path)

Still no luck, $PATH is not updated and i can't run an executable file inside ndk-bundle

```
$ PATH=$PATH:/c/Users/Karlo/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle

$PATH bash:/c/Users/Karlo/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Karlo/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Program: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `export`

Try

```
$ export PATH=/c/Users/Karlo/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle:$PATH
```

**EDIT**

For example:

```
chin@SGNPC0FTMSP12 MINGW64 ~
$ echo $PATH
/c/users/chin/devs/tools/ant/apache-ant-1.9.9/bin:/opt/subversion/bin:/c/users/chin/jdk1.7.0_79/bin:/c/Users/chin/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/chin/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/1E/NomadBranch:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/1E/NomadBranch:/cmd:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/c/users/chin/jdk1.7.0_79/bin:/c/users/chin/devs/tools/maven/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin

chin@SGNPC0FTMSP12 MINGW64 ~
$ export PATH=/c/users/chin/devs/tools/ant/apache-ant-1.9.9/bin2:$PATH

chin@SGNPC0FTMSP12 MINGW64 ~
$ echo $PATH
/c/users/chin/devs/tools/ant/apache-ant-1.9.9/bin2:/c/users/chin/devs/tools/ant/apache-ant-1.9.9/bin:/opt/subversion/bin:/c/users/chin/jdk1.7.0_79/bin:/c/Users/chin/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/chin/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/1E/NomadBranch:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/1E/NomadBranch:/cmd:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/c/users/chin/jdk1.7.0_79/bin:/c/users/chin/devs/tools/maven/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin
```

Comment: Are the executables directly under `/c/Users/Karlo/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle`? e.g. `/c/Users/Karlo/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/binary`, if they are not, then you may need to update the export accordingly, e.g. `$ export PATH=/c/Users/Karlo/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Updates to variables already in the environment are `export`ed automatically. If you run `export testVar=one` and then `testVar=two`, and run `env` to look at environment variables, you'll see that `testVar` has the value `two`.