# Trying to run Rscript from command line: Rscript command not found

Tags: r, windows, command-line, git-bash

I am new to learning R and working in command line. I am attempting to run an R script from command line, however I am getting an error line.

```
bash: Rscript: command not found
```

I have searched for a couple hours, tried uninstalling & re-installing R, tried adding Rscript.exe to Path in 'system environment variables'...

When I run `echo $PATH` I can confirm that the path is listed: `C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.0/bin/Rscript.exe`

I am working from the same directory as the R script I am attempting to run.

For reference, I am running Windows 11, R 4.3.0, and using Git Bash.

I have found some similar questions on here, but none of the answers are working for me. I also am at a low level of knowledge on this topic and struggling to follow some suggestions.

Anyhow, if anyone is able to help me out I would super appreciate it! Happy to answer any questions with more details, I just don't know what I need to include.

Comment: You may need to try [`Rscript.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764080/1968) (instead of just `Rscript`); be sure to also update the `PATH` environment variable as required: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45629314/1968

Comment: I had not understood how to update the PATH environment variable before, but that link helped - thanks! I successfully updated it (verified by `$ echo $PATH`). I then tried executing both `$ Rscript script_file.R` and `$ Rscript.exe script_file.R`, but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $PATH variable should contain the directory, not the executable. Assuming  the command is at `C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.0/bin/Rscript.exe`, then `echo $PATH` needs to show `C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.0/bin`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In a new session, here is what happened: `echo $PATH` showed `:/home/mydirectory/4-4.3.0/bin/`. I did `export PATH="C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.0/bin:"$PATH`, repeated `echo $PATH`, and it showed `C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.0/bin::/home/mydirectory/4-4.3.0/bin/`. Then I tried to run `Rscript script_file.R` and `Rscript.exe script_file.R`, but neither one is working still.

Comment: One hypothesis is that the way the path has to be specified in git bash for Windows is not "C:/...". You could try "/c/Program..." instead.

The other thing to watch out is the space in "Program Files". To prevent the shell from interpreting the space as a separator you can quote the path (which you already did) or you can escape the space character, i.e.  Program\ Files .

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for your help! What finally worked was `"/c/Program..."`.