# Git Bash for Windows does not see custom command php8

Tags: php, windows, git-bash

I have installed on Windows 10, both php 7.4 and php 8.1 in different folders PHP7 and PHP8. I have put C:/PHP7 in the PATH (environment variable) and now when I type php in the terminal (CMD, PowerShell and Git Bash) is running php7.

For php8 I have made a custom command *php8* by creating a *php8.cmd* file with this simple content:

```
"C:/PHP8/php.exe"  %*
```

I have placed the folder where the file is located in the PATH.

All good. Now when I type php8 in Command Line or PowerShell is running php 8. But if i type php8 in the Git Bash it says `bash: php8: command not found`

Somehow the Git Bash for Windows does not see the new custom command. I am not sure if I need to make a separate *.sh* file in which to put the equivalent content from the *php8.cmd* file or if is just a problem of configuring Git Bash to see the *php8.cmd* file.

Also I do not know what is the equivalent of   `"C:/PHP8/php.exe"  %*` in shell script.

**Can anyone help with this?**

I am doing this because I have an application based on Laravel8 (using php 7.4) and I want to switch it on Laravel 9 (which requires php 8). So I want to start a separate folder where to test the application using Laravel 9 (to see which changes I need to make to the code base or which dependencies need to upgrade). In my PhpStorm I am using Git Bash as the integrated terminal, and that's why I want that custom command php8 to work in Git Bash, too.

Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git Bash doesn't see my PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681101/git-bash-doesnt-see-my-path)

Comment: I made it work by placing in .bash_profile file an alias command like this php8=/path/to/php8 executable. Now I can run php8 artisan commands using PHP 8. Still had a problem with composer update (which used the default PHP 7) but I run the command with -- ignore-platform-reqs flag and now my application runs on Laravel 9

Comment: Great you found a solution! I added this as an answer with additional details, so others can benefit from your solution, if you accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the path to your php8 binaries (executables on Windows) to your environment.

**On Linux**
For example add `php8=/usr/bin/php8` alias to `.bash_profile` (if using bash) on Linux. You can find out the path by running `which php` in the shell.

**On Windows**
Find out the executable's path by running `where php.exe` in the Terminal/PS. Then add this path to the user's `PATH` variable in system settings.

---

You should then be able to use `php8` to run php commands in php8.

Also ensure composer uses the correct php version either by adding `--ignore-platform-reqs` argument or setting the following in `composer.json`

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "8.0.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: This is only an example. The most common distros ship with bash.

Comment: I think the answer should mention clearly that you have to create a php8 command file which to run PHP8 binaries.