# Composer not working in Git Bash showing 'which: no php in'

Tags: composer-php, git-bash

When running composer command like composer -v it shows

> `which: no php in (/c/Users/Vincent/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Vincent/bin:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/Program Files/PuTTY:/c/xampp/php:/c/Program Files (x86)/instantclient_19_12:/c/composer:/cmd:/c/Users/Vincent/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Users/Vincent/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/instantclient_19_12:/c/xampp/php:/c/composer:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl) /c/composer/composer: line 14: php: command not found`

but it works when using CMD

Comment: `php: command not found` where is the php executable?

Comment: im using xampp so it's in the C:\xampp\php. tho if i use CMD or Powershell it works

Comment: It probably isn't related to your problem, but I would recommend switching to WSL or use a linux docker image.

Comment: what is your concrete question? and please add the output of `composer diagnose`  to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add `C:\xampp\php\php.exe` to your Windows PATH.

##### Step by step:

Environment variables > User variables > Select PATH and press Edit > Add this path.

Comment: don't think its Environment Variables coz its working in CMD and Powershell but checking in ENV, its already in the PATH

Comment: @VincentDapiton have you tried to reopen the terminal after updating Path? And maybe this would help https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764080/17652912.